# Можно ли по AP Яндекс.Карты получить рейтинг компании, отзывы?

Tags: yandex-places-api

Можно ли по AP Яндекс.Карты получить рейтинг компании, отзывы? Если это возможно, то дайте, пожалуйста, какой-нибудь пример.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже что нет. По крайней мере ни в документации, ни в ответе сервера по организациям не нашёл никакой информации по отзывам. Более того, полагаю, что отзывы не являются частью "Технологий Яндекса", а взяты со сторонних ресурсов.